# Passing $(this) into d3 selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

How may I pass the self `$(this)` parameter into the d3 selector?

http://jsfiddle.net/6q0vvsja/

```
function d3_bar(self, dataset, barPadding) {

   var w = parseInt(d3.select(".barChart").style("width"),10), // select(self)
       h = parseInt(d3.select(".barChart").style("height"),10); // select(self)

    var svg = d3.select(".barChart") // select(self)
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

    svg.selectAll("rect")
        .data(dataset)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return i * (w / dataset.length);
        })
        .attr("y", function(d) {
            return h - (d * 4);
        })
        .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
        .attr("height", function(d) {
            return d * 4;
        })
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
        });

}

$('.barChart').each(function(i) { 

    var self = $(this),
        nums = self.data('value').split(',').map(Number);

        d3_bar(self, nums, 1);

});
```

Comment: Did you try to just pass in the element like so  `var svg = d3.select(self[0])` ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you can simply to `d3.select(this)`.

Comment: How will that know which initiation of the each its in, though?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `self` variable is a *jQuery object* and D3js will expect a *selector* or *DOM Element (Node)*.

> **d3.select(selector)**
>
> Selects the first element that matches the specified selector string, returning a single-element selection. If no elements in the current document match the specified selector, returns the empty selection. If multiple elements match the selector, only the first matching element (in document traversal order) will be selected.
>
> **d3.select(node)**
>
> Selects the specified node. This is useful if you already have a reference to a node, such as d3.select(this) within an event listener, or a global such as document.body. This function does not traverse the DOM.

-

> **Selecting Elements**
>
> ...These methods can also accept nodes, which is useful for integration with third-party libraries such as jQuery

To get the underlying JavaScript DOM element from a *jQuery object* you can just do

```
$('#myElem')[0];
```

So in your case you can pass in the JavaScript DOM element to the `d3.select` like so

```
var svg = d3.select(self[0])...
```

Why and how this works is explained [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_select).

```js
function d3_bar(self, dataset, barPadding) {

  var w = parseInt(d3.select(".barChart").style("width"),10);
  var h =  parseInt(d3.select(".barChart").style("height"),10);

  var svg = d3.select(self[0])
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

  svg.selectAll("rect")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * (w / dataset.length);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return h - (d * 4);
  })
  .attr("width", w / dataset.length - barPadding)
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d * 4;
  })
  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return "rgb(0, 0, " + (d * 10) + ")";
  });

}

$('.barChart').each(function(i) { 

  var self = $(this),
      nums = self.data('value').split(',').map(Number);

  d3_bar(self, nums, 1);

});
```

```css
.barChart:first-child {
  height:200px;
  width:500px;
}

.barChart:last-child {
  height:10px;
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="barChart" data-value="5,10,13,19,21,25,22,18,15,13,11,12,15,20,18,17,16,18,23,25"></div>
<div class="barChart" data-value="1,5,2,2,5,1,0,7,5,3"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://alignedleft.com/content/03-tutorials/01-d3/d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not mix up jQuery object with `d3.js`. `var self = $(this)`, `self` is a jQuery object, `d3.js` does not recognize it.

Comment: How would you pass the selector into the function?

Comment: can can pass class name as string